# Git: Commit a subset of modified/untracked files

Tags: git

I made some changes on my master branch. Now I want to persist my changes in several commits.

Let's say this is the result of `git status`:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   ../../../.gitignore
    modified:   ../java/file1.java
    modified:   ../java/file2.java
    modified:   package-lock.json
    modified:   package.json
    modified:   src/index.js

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    src/components/authentication/
    src/components/route/
    src/helpers/
```

How can I commit `file1` and `file2` in one commit, and `package.json`  and `package-lock.json` in the next commit? I thought of creating a new branch and moving my changes to that branch and then commit them, but I don't know how to move only a subset of these files.

Comment: This is where the fact that Git makes new commits from whatever is in the *index*, not whatever is in the *work-tree*, is helpful. The index is also called the *staging area*, perhaps because you arrange files on/in it like you would on a stage for filming or photography, before you use `git commit` to make the snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just only add the files to the index you want to commit.

```
git add ../java/file1.java
git add ../java/file1.java
git commit -m "First commit"

git add package-lock.json
git add package.json
git commit -m "Second commit"
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like you would do any other commit :

```
git add ../java
git commit -m "Updated file1 and file2"
git add package*.json
git commit -m "Updated package.json"
```